# CSS Style in Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Hi am new to Samsung Smart TV App,

I want to create some rich user interface with CSS and Javascript. I think Twitter Bootstrap is a good choice for this. But i cannot use bootstrap's class properties in my application. Guide me how to use twitter bootstrap framework in Samsung Smart TV App.

Comment: What platform version do you use? Check if it is supported: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Spec

Comment: Am using SDK 4.0 Beta. Is there any issue with this?

Comment: I forked bootstrap to my github and added some files needed to run it on Samsung Smart TV. I made few tests on it on SDK3.5 and it looks promising. Just check it out: https://github.com/dobiatowski/bootstrap

Comment: I have exported your files to app. In Index page i cannot navigate. How to focus the link using remote and how to navigate to other pages?

Comment: using mouse ;) remote controller is not supported yet ;)

Comment: Ohhhh Nooo... If you can please fix it also...?
In the same time thank you for your comment @Dobiatowski

Comment: It is not fix it is a feature ;) and it is not so easy part. At Monday I'll try to upload something.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used bootstrap in one of the apps I created.  Just add the bootstrap code to the project's directory and reference it from the index.html like you would with any style sheet.

Also make sure that you include the following at the top of all of the individual scene style sheets

```
@import url("<PATH TO BOOTSTRAP>/bootstrap.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `sf.core.loadCSS();` in your application. Just see [guide](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00009/sfcore_loadcss.html). There is analogous method for [JS including](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00009/sfcore_loadjs.html) too.

If you're using AppsFramework 2.0 app structure (Basic App Project) you should place it in your `app/init.js` like this:

```
function onStart() {
    sf.core.loadCSS([
        "app/stylesheets/file1.css",
        "app/stylesheets/file2.css"
    ], function () {
        // callback on file loading
    });
}
```

Callback function isn't mentioned in documentation, but it works (I'm sure for JS, CSS should work same way).

But if you're using "Javascript App Project" template (the old one), then you can place mentioned `<style>@import url();</style>` in your root `index.html`.